# PrimeNG radio button selecting multiple items

Tags: angular, radio-button, primeng

I'm creating multiple radio buttons dynamically using `*ngFor`, the problem is that it lets me select multiple items from the UI, my code is the following:

```
<div class="p-col-12">
    <p>Tipo de pregunta</p>
        <div *ngFor="let tipo_pregunta of tipos_pregunta">
            <p-radioButton formControlName="tipo_de_pregunta" inputIt="tipo_pregunta.value" name="tipo_pregunta" [value]="tipo_pregunta" [label]="tipo_pregunta.label" class="p-mb-3"></p-radioButton>
        </div>
</div>
```

If I create the buttons statically, such as:

```
<p-radioButton name="groupname" value="ps3" formControlName="console"></p-radioButton>
<p-radioButton name="groupname" value="ps4" formControlName="console"></p-radioButton>
<p-radioButton name="groupname" value="ps5" formControlName="console"></p-radioButton>
```

I have the same issue, any solution?

NOTE: When I submit the form, it just shows the last value I have clicked on, which means the bug is just visual, but it's still confusing and I would like to fix it.

Comment: Can you create a StackBlitz or at least share your TS code please?

Comment: try removing the name attribute, you are already having formControlName in radio fields.

Comment: @Antikhippe I created a stackblitz, surprisingly, it works there :/ https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-starter-example-xtngxj?file=src/app/app.component.html StackBlitz is using PrimeNG 7 and I'm using PrimeNG 10 in my project, could be a bug?

Comment: @FlowMafia I can see it is already working fine on stackblitz.Only one gets selected.

Comment: @Utkarsh that's my point, don't know if it's a PrimeNG 10 bug or some other kind of issue, I tried removing all my styles to see if it was some style doing weird stuff but no, it was not that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it works with PrimeNG 7 but not with PrimeNG 10, there is an issue opened on their github: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/9440

Here is a workaround while waiting for a fix:

```
this.questionForm.valueChanges.subscribe(e => {
  this.questionForm.setValue(e, { emitEvent: false });
});
```

See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-radiobutton-demo-p8f77b?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Edit: it seems it will be fixed in PrimeNG [10.0.4](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/9162#issuecomment-707310462)

Comment: i casually have the 10.0.3 version, either way, the workaround did the trick, thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

For anybody who is stuck on this issue, I had missed on the name attribute of radio button, the group of radio buttons should have the same name for p-radioButton . I gave same names for the radio button and it worked.

In the below eaxmple both p-radioButton have same value in the name attribute

> 

```
            <p-radioButton name="componentName" value="ComponentName1" formControlName="componentName" inputId="city1"></p-radioButton>
            <label for="city1">ComponentName1</label>
        </div>
        <div class="p-field-radiobutton">
            <p-radioButton name="componentName" value="ComponentName2" formControlName="componentName" inputId="city2"></p-radioButton>
            <label for="city1">ComponentName2</label>
        </div>
```